# How to find the external SdCard path in Android Marshmallow 6.0 using cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am unable to find the external storage path.
Till Android 5.0, the code working fine but for Android Marshmallow 6.0, unable to read external card path
file:///storage/B6BC-44F5 --> This path read externalSdcard but its code is static.
Can any one tell me how can I find the path.
Till Android 5.0 ---> cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "/../../../sdcard1/ is working fine for external SdCard Path but now its working.
Please help me out and Thanks in advance

Comment: cordova.file.externalRootDirectory is the one which is used to get sd card root directory. It works fine in Android Marshamallow. Check out this working sample which is tested on Android M - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: Will you please tell me Which Version of cordova you are using and which cordova API level is that ?

Comment: Have tried using both cordova 5.x and cordova 6.x versions

Comment: I am using cordova version 6.3.0 ? You tell which version you are using

Comment: tried cordova 6.2